# artwork_url is null in track lists, has value for single track. Bug?

Tags: soundcloud

A random query like

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?genre=Rnbhiphop

gives something like

```
[  
   {  
      "kind":"track",
      "id":161532719,
      (...)
      "artwork_url":null,
      (...)
   },
{  
      "kind":"track",
      "id":161532718,
      (...)
      "artwork_url":null,
      (...)
   },
   (..)
]
```

In many, many cases, artwork_url is null, although this is not consistent.

However, when looking at the single track id 161532719 (first in list above) with

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/161532719.json

we get

```
{  
   "kind":"track",
   "id":161532719,
   (...)
   "artwork_url":"http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000087026689-ogd56p-large.jpg?e76cf77",
   (...)
}
```

... which strangely enough reveals that track 161532719 HAS a valid artwork_url. The same is the case with many other tracks.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I have this problem. Have you found a sollution?!

Comment: `if(tracks.artwork_url == null){
   console.log(tracks.avatar_url);
   $('.imageTrack').css('content', 'url(' + tracks.avatar_url.replace('large', 't500x500') + ')').fadeIn( "slow" );
  }else{
   console.log(tracks.artwork_url);
   $('.imageTrack').css('content', 'url(' + tracks.artwork_url.replace('large', 't500x500') + ')').fadeIn( "slow" );
  }`

Comment: I tried this but `avatar_url` returns `'undefined'`

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet. To be honest, I thought that SoundCloud were handling their technical support here on SO, but...

Comment: This is quite a major issue for anyone trying to build there own soundcloud application... I think the problem lies when the owner of the track hasn't given a specific song artwork? But that is why I tried avatar_url but that returns undefined!

Comment: As I wrote in my original question, the artwork is there when you look at the track URL, just not in the query result. And yes, I'd say it's a major issue.

Comment: Bounty hasn't worked...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the collection endpoint (in this case genre), has a backend bug where the artwork is not fetched.

```
null
```

is not the same as undefined, rather it is intentionally set. If you encounter a null value, you can use data gathered from the single track endpoint, aggregate it to the tracks data from there.

If you choose to do this, I recommend firing the request for tracks endpoint the second you have the id you need, and updating using the id.

Answer (score 1):

If the uploader of the track didn't attach an image to it, Soundcloud will show the uploader avatar instead.
But, when you will try to get the "artwork_url" from a JSONObject of that kind of a track, you will get "null".

To fix this issue, and to use the same logic Soundcloud use just add:

```
String artUrl = trackJson.getString("artwork_url");
if (artUrl == "null") {
    JSONObject user = trackJson.getJSONObject("user");
    artUrl = user.getString("avatar_url");
}
```